# create a main function in python and passing arguments

Tags: python

Iam new with python and I did my first program in Python with jupyter notebook.
Here my tutor, said to me that I have to converti it into a script .py with passing arguments.
I try to do this byte per byte .

Can you just help me how to begin the script and passing New1 and New as arguments.

```
df_equipment = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Demonstrator/Downloads/New1.csv',delimiter=';', parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format = True)
df_energy2=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Demonstrator/Downloads/New2.csv', delimiter=';', parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format = True)
```

Thank you

Comment: Search for `argparse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [tutorial for using sys.argv](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/system/python-sys-argv).  When you are ready to be more robust about argument parsing, look into this [argparse tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html).

Comment: And then, to create a dataframe I do pd.read_csv(argv[0])?? It 's a little bit not clear for me

Comment: `sys.argv[0]` is the path/name of the script itself.  if you have two parameters, you want `sys.argv[1]` and `sys.argv[2]`.   The best way to understand is to copy the tutorial code into a new script, play with it and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from [Pythion Tutorials](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm)

```
def printme( str ):
   "This prints a passed string into this function"
   print str
   return;

# Now you can call printme function
printme("I'm first call to user defined function!")
printme("Again second call to the same function")
```

Comment: Yes. You can add it to a .py file

Comment: This is the main function?